# Win Mobile6 GPS Inaccuracy

Tags: c#, gps

I am writing an application that utilizes the built in GPS on the Motorola MC75. I have it configured properly and running the test solution that comes with Win6 SDK. It works fine and the coordinates when plugged into Google maps pick an accurate location. However the longitude and latitude fluxes substantially (substantially when trying to measure distances 25 or so feet apart). While standing still it will usually flux between .0002 to .0003 which is about 36 or so feet.

Is there anyway to improve the accuracy? I know it is possible to change QoP in the remote registry but I am not sure how that changes it because I am unable to find any documentation.

Any suggestions? I will surely vote for the most helpful answer.

Thanks in advance.
Zach

Answer (score 2):

The problem with GPS is that its only accurate up to ~10 meters (10 meters = 32.808399 feet).  There are technologies to assist in more accurate location, such as WAAS.

"...For example, imagine that a certain GPS receiver collected 1000 data points under ideal conditions. It is conceivable that the best data point could be accurate to better than 0.01 meters, and the worst, accurate to only 15 meters..." - [GPS Link](http://www.romdas.com/technical/gps/gps-acc.htm)

Other devices use accelerometers and digital compasses to help get a more "local" accuracy to movement.  Using such devices one can fill in the gaps between the GPS points to create a more fluid system.